# House Advantage of Coin Toss and Dice Roll

Tags: probability, game-theory, gambling

**Question**

You flip a coin,

If it is heads, use 1 die

If it is tails, use 2 dice

If the total of the die/dice is X≤5, you lose

If the total of the die/dice is X=6, it is a push

If the total of the die/dice is X≥7, you win

Find the probability of winning, expected and house advantage.

This is how far I got (I may have made a mess of things, and I don't know if I'm correct to assume "expected" means "expected value"):

**For expected value,**

E[X|Tails]= (1/6)(1+2+3+4+5+6)= 3.5

E[X|Heads]= (2+12)(1/36)+(3+11)(2/36)+(4+10)(3/36)+(5+9)(4/36)+(6+8)(5/36)+7(6/36) = 7

Using the linearity of expectation,

E[X]= (3.5)(1/2)+(7)(1/2) = 5.25

**For probability of winning,**

P(X≥7|tails)= 0

P(X≥7|heads)= 21/36

P(X≥7)= (21/36)*(1/2) = 21/72

**For house advantage,**

Given a win pays a to 1, where a>0, and the bet size is b>0, then,

P(X=ab)=p, p>0, where p= 21/72  (from above)

P(X=-b)=q, q>0, where q= (1- 21/72 - (1/6+5/36)*1/2) = 40/72 (from above)

P(X=0)=r, r≥0, where r=(1/2)(1/6 + 5/36) = 11/72 (from above)

and

H0(B,X) = −ap+q = -a(21/72)+40/72

and

H(B,X) = (−ap+q)/p+q = (-a(21)+40)/ 61

Comment: What if you flip a head and use one die?  How do you win or lose then?

Comment: @fleablood, you are right, I will edit the question

Comment: Why write the probs as decimals?  Wouldn't it be both easier and more accurate to write them as fractions over the denominator $72$?

Comment: @fleablood yep, it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

As you say, your chance of a win is $\frac {21}{72}$.  Your chance of a push is $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 16 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 5{36}=\frac {11}{72}$ where the first term comes from heads+$6$ and the second comes from tails plus a sum of $6$.  Your chance of a loss is then $\frac {40}{72}$ and your expectation on a bet of $1$ is $\frac {21-40}{72}=-\frac {19}{72}$